# How to align QProgressBar label in QGIS messagebar?

Tags: qgis, python, qt4

Unable to align the QProgressbar label in Qgis Messagebar. see the image below

[image]

While progressbar is updating,the label is vanished. so i tried the alignment for progressbar as shown below but its not working.

[image]

My code is:

```
widget = self.iface.messageBar().createMessage("Global Error Marker"," Downloading errors from data base . . .")
       prgBar = QProgressBar()
       prgBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
       prgBar.setValue(0)
       prgBar.setMaximum(100)           
       widget.layout().addWidget(prgBar)
       self.iface.messageBar().pushWidget(widget, self.iface.messageBar().WARNING)


       for i in range(1,100)
               errCount += 1
               prgBar.setValue(i)


       self.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
       self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Moreover i need to set the focus on progressbar and need python code to use 'DoEvents'

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
prgBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
```

It should give you what you need

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with your code but it stands in unchanged.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. i am using Qgis Master 1.9 with python 2.7